# Why do my inline-block elements keep wrapping?

Tags: css

Here's is a little example: http://www.cssdesk.com/QXmaG

HTML :

```
<div id="blockHolder">
  <div class="inlineblock"></div>
  <div class="inlineblock"></div>
  <div class="inlineblock"></div>
  <div class="inlineblock"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.inlineblock{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#blockHolder{
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

And I want for the `inline-block` items to keep lining up (horizontally) in its parent container `#blockHolder` in this example.

Why does `white-space:nowrap` not work for this and how can I achieve that desired effect?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Your demo seems to be doing the exact behavior you're asking for.

Comment: try adding overflow : auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add, `whitespace: nowrap` to the `#blockHolder`: http://jsfiddle.net/3LQJG/.

```
#blockHolder {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The white-space:nowrap specify that the text in paragraphs will never wrap, doesn't work for divs.
You need to add a width to the #blockHolder.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table-cell;`

```
.inlineblock{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  display:table-cell;
  background:red;

}
```

See : http://www.cssdesk.com/maCKQ

Answer (score 0):

In `body`, add:

```
width: 100%;
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://www.cssdesk.com/fwzMZ)